# I have a change event on a text input and a click event on a button. Why does the former fire first?

Tags: javascript, forms, events

I'm working on a JavaScript 'form' (it's not actually a form - it's a Knockout interface that makes a request to another JavaScript object, but that's not important) and I'm a bit worried about some behavior I'm not sure I can rely upon.

Let's say I have an input and I've attached a change event, either natively through onChange or via jQuery change. That change event updates a model that I'm going to validate and then send off to the server as part of my form 'submission'.

I also have a button with a click event that performs the submission.

If I click the button, as far as I can tell, the form element change event triggers first. But can I rely on this behaviour? Is the fact the change event fires first part of a recognized specification, or just a browser implementation detail?

I took a look at the events specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/) but couldn't find an answer to my specific question, just that click, blur and focus events are treated synchronously - that is, they're added to a queue and executed in order. But I don't know if the order is consistent between user agents.

Is this behaviour guaranteed by any specification?

Comment: Does empty form without any input still triggers change event, when `form.submit()`'ed? I think it's bubbling event from input field.